# How to do a broad-match search with TSQL FreeText search with numeric values?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, full-text-search

I am trying to do a free text search on terms like "sony model number np-fx110" or "carrying case for sony sz-vgn770N" or "asus laptop model g60v".

I know that freetext treats numbers like noise, so I figured I would edit out numbers from the noise SQL Server 2008 noiseENU.txt file but I'm unable to locate any noise files on my server.

The FTData directory only contains a bunch of 2kb xml files and an empty FilterData folder.

I've got a split Function that will return all words in a given string with a split character of a space.  I need a CTE that will concatenate the AND text for each word in returned from the SPLIT() function.

```
> SELECT *  FROM MyTable WHERE
> Description LIKE '%asus%'  AND
> Description LIKE '%laptop%'  AND
> Description LIKE '%model%'  AND
> Description LIKE '%g60v%'
```

Essentially the model number can be anywhere in the description field.  I can easily do a LIKE [model number], however I would want to match that up with other words contained in the description.

This doesn't seem like an optimal approach, but workable.  Any other suggestions on how to tackle this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE

Here is the result of running "exec sp_help_fulltext_catalogs"

```
> ftcatid:5 NAME: CTIMytemDataCatalog   
> PATH: NULL                            
> STATUS: 0 
> NUMBER_FULLTEXT_TABLES: 1
```

UPDATE

A problem arises when the model number is simply a number, such as "4" in "iphone 4".

I am already dynamically building a CONTAINS query, inserting AND in between each term.  However, here are some issues:

```
> **WHERE CONTAINS(*, 'iphone AND 4 AND battery')** - returns 0 results
> **WHERE FREETEXT(*, 'iphone 4 battery')** - is matching for iphone
> OR battery which is sub-optimal
> **WHERE CONTAINS(*, '"iphone 4" AND "battery"')** - returns the most
> accurate result set
```

Given these findings I'm thinking that I should maintain a list of these "special cases" in a table, and generate my CONTAINS query dynamically based on this.

Any suggestions about this approach?

Comment: NULL indicates the default directory determined during installation. (This is the Ftdata subdirectory under the Microsoft SQL Server directory; for example, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTData.)   (from books online)

Comment: Thanks Lazy... I read that, and looked in the FTData directory... as listed above, not much in there except some XML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a full text index?

You are correct that SQL treats "1" or "2" as noise by default (you can change this)... but it should find "g60v" or "sz-vgn770N" no problem.  I have used FTS in similar fashion searching a catalog of books by ISBN and it worked fine.

Lastly, I may be wrong on this one... but I don't think the noise file gets created until you actually build/use FTS.

Also note that searching FTS isn't similar to using a like statement.  [Read up on the different methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879300.aspx) for searching FTS with Books Online if you're not familiar with the syntax.

A query like this should work for your needs:  (how I use FTS with my book catalog search)

```
WHERE FREETEXT (*, 'g60v asus laptop model' );
```

Read more about freetext queries here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx

Comment: Lazy: I know I could do a search gof "g60v" and find it, however if the search is "laptop model g60v asus" or "g60v model asus", no go.  I also already have a full text catalog defined for one of my tables.

Comment: Try it like this...:  WHERE CONTAINS(Description, ' "g60v" OR "laptop" or "model" or "asus" ')

Comment: Or like this...: WHERE CONTAINS(Description, ' "g60v" AND "laptop" AND "model" AND "asus" ')

Comment: I've updated my answer with the way I'd do it.  But the examples above in comments are another way.

Comment: Lazy:  With electronics, the actual product name or the model is just a number, as in "ipod 2" or "iphone 4".  So how would you structure a search for say, "64gb iphone 4" or "iphone 4 64gb"?  I am already auto inserting AND into a CONTAINS query, and getting no results when those single numbers are used.

Comment: In cases, such as "iphone 4" or "ipad 2", I may have to create a list of these values, check against it, and if exists, treat that as one term in my CONTAINS clause.  However this doesn't seem very scalable.

Comment: Yes, that's where editing your noise file becomes important.  I might try rebuilding the index to see if the noise file appears.  Also make sure you look in all the MSSQL sub folders under \Microsoft SQL Server\

Comment: Lazy: as I now understand it, "In SQL Server 2008 these noise word files, formerly stored in the file system, have been replaced with stoplists that are stored in the database".  I'm not sure how adding "iphone 4" will help me in this case, as it would simply exclude that.  See my last update above... I think that may be the way to go about this, unless there are better recommendations?

Comment: Oh and by the way.... you don't add iphone 4 to the noise list... you remove the number 4.

Comment: lazy:  Ah yes, I finally took a closer look at the errors, indicating that the search text contained a noise word.  I checked in Storage/Full Text Stoplists in the db, and there were no lists, so I am still at a loss as to where to edit the stoplist.  Finding the stoplist would be good, but for now I created an algorithm that satisfies the search needs.  Have you found the stop list?

Comment: I haven't played with it yet but I do see it documented here...:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx  I think with the views shown under the "Metadata" section at the bottom of the article you should be able to find it.

Comment: For those who may be stuck at this point as well, this article helps: http://soonyu-sql.blogspot.com/2010/12/fulltext-stoplist-sql-2008.html